# Merge [office365-addin] into [office365-apps]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag descriptions are exactly the same, except for the edit I've made in [office365-apps] a couple of days ago. There is no reason for there to be two tags for the same topic.

Note: there is no such thing as Office365 Addins. There are, however, office addins, which have their own tags such as [office-addins], [vsto], etc.